# Computing surface normal, floating point arithmetic

Tags: geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry

If I have a $n$-gon in $\mathbb{R^3}$, and I want to compute the surface normal, how can I get a value that minimizes error in a floating-point system? For example:

- Would I gain accuracy by first translating all vertices to the origin before performing further processing? Or would something be "lost in translation"?
- A typical way of finding the surface normal is to form two vectors from three points and compute the cross product. Which are the "best" points to choose?

Comment: How are you generating the vertices? If they're stored as floating point numbers $x_i\gg1$, then you have accuracy issues which will be magnified no matter how you compute the normal. If you have access to some arbitrary precision representation of the vertices, I would probably use this to come up with unit vectors along the edges and compute the normal using those. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This may be a question better suited for: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The vertices are exported from a modeling program, and stored as 32 bit floats. I understand that error is unavoidable, but I was wondering if there is a method to ensure that the error is as small as possible - it seems that some choices ought to be better than others?

Comment: It really depends on why you think the n-gon provided really does lie in a plane. Perfection in that is impossible short of certain extensions of rational arithmetic. If I were you, I would be taking random samples from the program that supplies the n-gons, for each one calculate the $n(n-1)/2$ pairwise cross products, normalize those at unit length and adjust $\pm$ signs as necessary, and do some statistics on error. Or, find the center of gravity of the vertices and work that in...

Comment: @Clinton: I assume you didn't intend to flag your own question as off-topic?

Comment: @ZevChonoles I wasn't sure if dls was correct in saying that it would be more appropriate for the Scientific Computing site, so I flagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input points are given in single precision, and you can almost certainly do your computation with double-precision intermediates, your main source of error will be uncertainty in the exact position of the input points.

Ideally, I think you should want to compute the normal vector as the cross product of two diagonals: $(v_i-v_j)\times(v_k-v_l)$ with $i,j,k,l$ chosen to maximize the *magnitude* of the cross product. This at once selects against using very short diagonals (whose direction is more uncertain than long ones), *and* against using nearly parallel diagonals (where small errors in the directions of each diagonal could lead to large errors in the final normal). However, there are on the order of $n^4$ possible combinations of diagonals, so unless you have unlimited time or $n$ is always small, you don't want to try all combinations.

One possible heuristic would be to choose $i$ and $j$ as the endpoints of the *longest* diagonal (which can be found in $O(n^2)$ time) and then try cross products with all combinations of $k$ and $l$, also in $O(n^2)$ time.

Faster but more crudely, choose $i$ arbitrarily, then choose $j$ so the length of $v_i-v_j$ is maximal. Choose $k$ to maximize the distance from $v_k$ to the diagonal $v_iv_j$, and finally choose $l$ to maximize the cross product.

In any case, don't attempt to translate to polygon anywhere before your computations. That will just lead to intermediates of the form $(a+t)-(b+t)$ rather than $a-b$, and the former cannot possibly give better results than the latter. At best it is harmless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I asked around at some other locations, and several people pointed me to this algorithm: http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~gordon/plane.pdf, You might be interested in having a look. There's an additional explanation here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~ug/slide/pipeline/assignments/backfacecull.shtml